# How to calculate difference between entry and previous entry in column for R table?

Tags: r

I am attempting to generate a feature to my data table in R that will calculate the difference between the current entry of the column and the one previous. This column is a time variable telling me hour-min-secs and I am hoping to create a variable telling me how much time elapses between each record. Seems straightforward.

I've been trying to work solely with dplyr, but the lag() function isn't doing the trick. Here is what I am attempting to do, in a nutshell.

```
ah <- data %>% 
  group_by(person_id) %>% 
  arrange(Date, Time) %>% 
  mutate(time_gap = Time - lag(Time))
```

However, I am getting an error for this code. 
"Non-numeric argument to binary operator". I am not sure why this coming out.

Comment: I think it is related to `Time` column.  Check the `str(data)` to find the class of 'Time' column

Comment: arkun, the class is "character". Should I coerce it to date? when I run str(data), it reports the variable as a Date object, but running class(data$Time) it gives me "character"

Comment: You should coerce to a datetime vector. See ?strptime

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This example below works.

```
# Create sample data frame
df <- data.frame(
  person_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  datetime = c(
  "2012-01-01 00:00:30", 
  "2012-01-01 00:01:00", 
  "2012-01-01 00:02:00", 
  "2020-01-01 00:00:35", 
  "2020-01-01 00:01:00", 
  "2020-01-01 00:02:33")
  )

# Convert character variable to datetime
df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$datetime)

# Calculate time deltas by person_id
ah <- df %>% 
  group_by(person_id) %>% 
  arrange(datetime) %>% 
  mutate(time_gap = datetime - lag(datetime))
```